# Error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I am attempting to install php on a VM running CentOS 7, but when I try to configure php, I run into the following error:

**My Configuration Settings:**

```
./configure --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --with-curl --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-zlib-dir --with-regex --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip --with-zlib --enable-inline-optimization --enable-mbregex --enable-opcache --enable-fpm --prefix=/usr/local/php
```

**Error:**

```
configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for additional information.
```

I've gone through about a dozen threads that saying that I need to install libc-client-devel, but when I try to do that (using yum), I get an error that the package doesn't exist.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my problem if anyone who looks at this later is wondering. I needed to enable the EPEL Repository for those missing packages to be available. After I imported that repository, everything installed fine.

Comment: how can i do this inside a docker file?